# I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a page scrolling effect on the website when some links are clicked

```
 $('nav a[href*="#"]').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate(keyframes:{
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100
    }, options:2000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has problems with parentheses. `(keyframes:...` is not valid Javascript.

Try this:

```
 $('nav a[href*="#"]').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({keyframes:{
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100
    }, options:2000});
  });
```